# Using $(document.on('click' with multiple selectors and checking if one click was fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the `class` was clicked on, then it would hit the method.

Right now, clicking on one of the `<div>` elements calls the method three times. I would like to group these div's together and check if one was called then trigger the method once. Otherwise nothing happens.

```
$(document.on('click', '.class1, .class2, .class3', (e) => { 

   someFunction();

}
```

I have tried getting the current `class` with this, but not been successful. As well as using `currentTarget`.

Any help? Not sure what to do about this as its the first time I have used JQuery.

Comment: Why don't you give all three div elements an additional, common class? Also, why not simply do this without jQuery?

Comment: jQuery is obselete, you should drop it in new projects.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa that's a rather bold statement. jQuery appear to be supported and getting new releases as far as I can see. And it can be very useful. Why exactly do you think it's "obsolete"??

Comment: You miss the closing parenthesis two places. It would work instead. `$(document).on('click', '.class1, .class2, .class3', (e) => { someFunction(); });` --- Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @ADyson everythingI don't know what they can update in it because the whole thing is just good for legacy and certainly not for new projects. It can be found quickly with some google search. If you are still not convince, please give me one feature that you need from jQuery and I will tell you the appropriate way.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I don't want to get into a long debate but... "the whole thing is just good for legacy and certainly not for new projects" ...that's just a repetition of your opinion and not an explanation of your reasoning. If the evidence can be found quickly perhaps you could take a moment to link me to your source. I'm sure everyone likes something different about jQuery but for me personally, amongst other things, I find the syntax style much briefer and easier to follow that native JS. That's not something you can easily replace. I could list other things too but it's too long.

Comment: @ADyson we can argue as much as you want you´ll be wrong. What syntax are you thinking of?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa "you´ll be wrong" . I can see this is going to be productive. A debate with an open mind. Fantastic. I assume you've been studying U.S. politics. Just for the sake of it, the most basic example: `$(".whatever").click(function() { });` is, to me, far clearer, briefer, quicker to type and easier to read than `document.querySelectorAll(".whatever").forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    });
});` It wins for convenience and readability on that alone every time, IMO. You may feel differently.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa P.S. I am well aware that some of the things which jQuery used to provide uniquely, or provide cross-browser compatibility for, now have equivalent functions, especially in ES6, or the compatibility is not an issue in newer browsers. But as we've seen above, the syntax is often clunky. And there are many projects which still have to provide backward compatibility, even for new pieces of work. Everything becomes obsolete eventually, but I think announcing the demise of jQuery is premature, to say the least. It's still useful to, and used by, millions of developers and websites.

Comment: A very high percentage of the millions of developers you are telling about don't even try to write decent code for their companies. In StackOverflow we aim to give the best technical answers. I think it is correct to say that jQuery is completely obsolete and wrong to say it still serve a purpose. Most of the backward compatibility exist in ES6 and they are simpler than the existing one, they target the proper browsers/clients. They are now advanced tool compare to jQuery. One reason why I see people keeping using jQuery is the lack of interest, lack of time and the legacy code.

Comment: If you have time and want to do things properly, just drop jQuery. I can't see what ES6 clunky synthax you are referencing to be better in jQuery so I can't debate on this unless you give an example, but you are still wrong. Considering I don't know any, and ES6 was built way after jQuery and those millions of users, I bet you are also having the wrong tought.

Answer (score 1):

See this example.

https://jsfiddle.net/efleon9/nz7dm2a4/2/

Or you can do, this:

```
$('button[class^="class"]').click(function(e){
     alert('fired2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do this with vanilla Javascript?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (['class1', 'class2', 'class3'].includes(e.target.className)) {
    console.log(`${e.target.className} clicked`);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="class1">class 1</div>
<div class="class2">class 2</div>
<div class="class3">class 3</div>
<div class="class4">class 4</div>
```

The same code in IE-compatible ES5:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (['class1', 'class2', 'class3'].indexOf(e.target.className) > -1) {
    console.log(e.target.className + ' clicked');
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="class1">class 1</div>
<div class="class2">class 2</div>
<div class="class3">class 3</div>
<div class="class4">class 4</div>
```